# How not to save a photo local?

Tags: android, camera, photo, android-camera

for my android application,I need to take a photo with the built-in camera and save it to a database in a blob field.

I can take a photo and save it to a blob field, but the device also saves the photo local. To avoid the device filling with photos, I don't want to save the photo local on the device, only in the db.

I'm using Android 2.3.3, my test device is a Samsung Galaxy S II with default photo-application.

How can I do this?

Thanx,

Robby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an own Activity to take the pictures.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

As I read you don't have to save your pictures there.

Answer (score 2):

After capturing photo using camera you can store the image in database using blob file. After storing in database is done you can delete the photo from that path.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: This is plan B. Not storing it at all would save some time and IO.